# iOS Application request faild when come back from background

Tags: objective-c, request, afnetworking, background-task

iOS Application request faild when come back from background,
I use AFNetworking in my Application,a lot of user use my app enter background but not kill app when they want to leave my app,when they come back from background after a long time,the home page requests always faild,
we statistical the error found , -1001 and -1009 take 90%,
any one know why?

Answer (score 0):

Your app's network will continue running in 180s, after that it will stop, 
if you need to continue network task, your app must support background mode.

you can check [the link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html), start from the chapter 'Implementing Long-Running Tasks'